# What does "F.I.T." stand for here?

Tags: abbreviations

Context ([New York Times](http://travel.nytimes.com/2010/06/20/travel/20hotels.html?pagewanted=all)),

> Despite all the sartorial trappings, guests dressed like any in your typical off-the-rack hotel. On a recent Monday, there were **F.I.T. parents** in the slate-gray lobby, and suits trading airport stories in the elevator. There’s a chatty cocktail scene at the lobby bar, but Rare, the fiery orange dining room, was desolate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In New York, there is the [Fashion Institute of Technology](http://www.fitnyc.edu/), which is part of the State University of New York.